# gridview Paging not selecting current page

Tags: javascript, gridview, checkbox

I have select all checkbox for checking/unchecking gridview as shown below:
[image]
when grid has one page only,everything workings fine, when there are multiple pages my JavaScript throws me an error

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'checked' of
>   undefined or null reference

Please find the javascript code

```
 function HeaderClick(CheckBox)
                {
                var MainGridView =document.getElementById("GriduwgDocuments");
                 if (CheckBox.checked == true)
                {
                for( var i=1; i < MainGridView.rows.length; i++)
               {
                 debugger;
               var chb = MainGridView.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes['1'].checked;
                    if (!chb.checked) {
              MainGridView.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes['1'].checked = true;
                                }
               }
               CheckBox.checked == true;
               }

               if (CheckBox.checked== false)
                {

                 for( var i=1; i < MainGridView.rows.length; i++)
               {
               var chb = MainGridView.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes['1'].checked;
                    if (!chb.checked) {
                     MainGridView.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes['1'].checked = false;
                                }
               }
                 CheckBox.checked=false;

               }

               }
```

Select all checkbox has

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Select All" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        onclick="javascript:HeaderClick(this);" OnCheckedChanged="cbSelectAll_CheckedChanged" />
```

and my grid is as follow :

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GriduwgDocuments" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" EnablePersistedSelection="true"
                            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" GridLines="None" Width="100%" PageSize="25">
                            <PagerSettings Position="Top"></PagerSettings>
                            <RowStyle CssClass="result-grid-row" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="result-grid-row-alternate" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="result-grid-row-selected" />
                            <HeaderStyle Height="20px" CssClass="result-grid-header" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBxSelect" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbRowChanged_CheckedChanged" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                            </Columns>
                            <PagerStyle CssClass="result-grid-pager-container" />
                            <PagerTemplate>
                                <uc:GridViewPager OnPageNumberChanged="GriduwgDocuments_OnPageNumberChanged" OnPageSizeChanged="GriduwgDocuments_OnPageSizeChanged"
                                    ID="GridViewPager2" runat="server" />
                            </PagerTemplate>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Could you please help me to understand what's going wrong here?
TIA.

Comment: looks like a conflict with your codebehind and Javascript. post your Javascript

Comment: @DaniDev , I already posted my script. are you lookin for code befind?

Comment: OK, Yes you have (my bad). What I believe is happening is that when you have multiple pages the rows past the intial page are not loaded on the page.  When your JavaScript is trying to iterate through to MainGridView.rows.length . it tries to read rows that do not exist in the current view.